# XCode - Dependencies for static build in xcframework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dependencies, xcframework

Dependencies in static build

I am creating a .xcframework which contains static builds of my SDK for consumption via CocoaPods and SPM.
The framework structure is:

```
MYSDKAssets.bundle
MySDK.xcframework
- info.plist
- ios-arm-64
    - MySDK.swiftmodule
    - MySDK.a
- ios-x86_64-simulator
    - MySDK.swiftmodule
    - MySDK.a
```

MySDK has two external dependencies: `GenericPubSub` and `GenericAnalytics`. The problem I am running into is when I try to install the SDK in an external app via CocoaPods, I am getting an error in the .swiftinterface file

`No such module GenericPubSub` on the `import GenericPubSub` line.

I've listed the dependencies in the podspec:

```
  spec.dependency 'GenericPubSub', '~> 1.0.0'
```

How can I fix this so that my static build can use external dependencies?